# Can Pyrex laboratory grade glassware be heated on a stovetop?

Tags: home-experiment, heat, equipment

I don't have access to a hot plate, I was wondering if Pyrex glass can be safely heated on a stove top. It isn't an open flame, it's a radiant stove top with an electric coil underneath a smooth counter. I believe the heating should be even because the coil heats the entire stove top evenly.

Comment: I think the main safety question here is what is inside the Pyrex container. Heating should, in general, not be a problem.

Comment: I agree with Zhe. I can't see any reason as to why using a stovetop would be any different than using a hotplate.

Comment: Rather than thermal shock, a bigger hazard might be that the stove surface is *very* hard. Borosilicate percolators came with a metal wire trivet to spread heat and prevent scratching against enameled burner tops; you might use  a bit of wire gauze for that purpose.